# Zbar iOS SDK does not scan barcodes on products

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

[image]Am trying scan a product using zbar samples provided in SDK, it scans bar codes present on screens, not on products, for instance i have a product with barcode number 6281022118063 which is a EAN 13 barcode printed on the product it doesn't scan, if i generate a barcode with the same number using some bar code generation websites, it scans perfectly fine.i tried scanning about 4 products the behavior is same, i made sure that EAN 13 symbology is set.

Comment: Upload a picture of the product barcode you are trying to scan

Comment: updated my question with image

Comment: I was able to scan that image using zbar just fine.